# Character not jumping correctly

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my character jump when I tap the screen.

I'm not to sure if this is the best way, tried searching but couldn't find a decent tutorial. So I used the same process that I used when changing sprite frames.

```
private int jumpDelay = 100;
private long lastFrameJumpDelay = 0;

public void jump(){

    long timeJump = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean jumping = true;
    int jumpCount = 0;

    if (jumping){
        if (timeJump > lastFrameJumpDelay + jumpDelay){
            lastFrameJumpDelay = timeJump;
            manYPos = manYPos - 20;//this is the y axis for my characte
            jumpCount ++;
            if (jumpCount == 10){
                jumping = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can tell when I click the screen it only jumps a little bit. In other words only goes through the if loop once. Not sure why its not moving 10 times with just one click.

Comment: Maybe because a `if` is not a loop ? you may want to use `while`

Comment: Sorry didn't explain that well. instead of going through the if statement repeatedly, untill jumping == false. It only goes through once.

Comment: Changed it to :while (jumpCount<10){
            if (timeJump > lastFrameJumpDelay + jumpDelay) {
                lastFrameJumpDelay = timeJump;
                manYPos = manYPos - 20;
                jumpCount ++;                                                                                        now when i click it still doesn't jump properly and if i click again it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Alright worked out my own mistake. I thought that

`long timeJump  = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Will some how keep a current time always, meaning it will always know the time.
But it doesn't it only keeps the time that it was made. So I had to put it into my while loop to make it work.